# Get all offers from all merchants using AMAZON API for a specific product

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I need to be able to get a listing of all offers for a product using the amazon API. This is the request I'm sending:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&SubscriptionId=&AssociateTag=&Version=2011-08-01&ItemId=B007IJQDQQ&IdType=ASIN&ResponseGroup=Offers&Condition=All&MerchantId=All
```

This is returning the follow under offers:

```
<Offers>
<TotalOffers>1</TotalOffers>
<TotalOfferPages>1</TotalOfferPages>
<MoreOffersUrl>
http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B007IJQDQQ%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJTZ6VROOTPJAPPWQ%26tag%3Damazoautom-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007IJQDQQ
</MoreOffersUrl>
<Offer>
<OfferAttributes>
<Condition>New</Condition>
</OfferAttributes>
<OfferListing>
<OfferListingId>
TR5sygI0VR7cwy3Hg0DBHwgCWFnkqXLyCR70jjMhy1h8gWlEisKYt5cqDbS2Fu1SEqDtfBILdxYDziJdFzfsqMpPJkBqcYV3DFovHx1nXWRy9wHS6CFZXknBvsCo1bxYS%2BsxAeYrZHrS6g6aakEJQA%3D%3D
</OfferListingId>
<Price>
<Amount>375</Amount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<FormattedPrice>$3.75</FormattedPrice>
</Price>
<AmountSaved>
<PercentageSaved>56</PercentageSaved>
<Availability>Usually ships in 1-2 business days</Availability>
<AvailabilityAttributes>
<IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>0</IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping>
</OfferListing>
</Offer>
</Offers>
```

As you can see it only returns the 1 offer even though it says there are 3 new offers. Does anyone know of a way to get all the offers and not just the lowest one? Merchant ID='ALL' doesn't do it, neither do any of the other response groups like offerFull, offerSummary, or offers.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The total offer attributes always remain the same i.e `1` even if I put `conditions => "All"`

Comment: It seems they have gotten rid of the 'multiple offers' option in 2011. See link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=78421